# Need to force a 404 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently redesigned my [college newspaper's website](http://bupd.me/) and have been doing everything I can to make sure the archives properly redirect. The site is powered by WordPress and the permalinks are set to `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/`.

Basically, WordPress takes a request like `www.bupipedream.com/*anything*/post_id/*anything*/` and redirects it to the post with that post_id whether or not the category or postname are correct.

This is causing problems when someone tries to access an old-URL like `www.bupipedream.com/Issues/443`, WordPress redirects them to the post that has a post_id of 443.

How can I stop WordPress from redirecting requests to `www.bupipedream.com/Issues`? I want WP to show a 404 instead.

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to ThinkingMonkey, but in reverse: block categories you want to 404:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(Issues|OtherCategoryToBlock)/
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Note on some lame hosting plans (mine), you may need to add "ErrorDocument 404 /404.html" in  your .htaccess or it might not send 404 content -- only the header. But anyway, the answer above worked well for me -- I was able to thwart some old malware URLs that were long expunged from the website after a rebuild. Google does not like seeing your index.php even after removing the malware -- they want to see a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have too many categories, you can add this soon after `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(category1|category2|category3|categoryn) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```